# Message Granularity for Message Queues and Service Buses

Tags: c#, message-queue, servicebus

I'm working on an application that may generate thousands of messages in a fairly tight loop on a client, to be processed on a server.  The chain of events is something like:

1. Client processes item, places in local queue.
2. Local queue processing picks up messages and calls web service.
3. Web service creates message in service bus on server.
4. Service bus processes message to database.

The idea being that all communications are asynchronous, as there will be many clients for the web service.  I know that MSMQ can do this directly, but we don't always have that kind of admin capability on the clients to set things up like security etc.

My question is about the granularity of the messages at each stage.  The simplest method would mean that each item processed on the client generates one client message/web service call/service bus message.  That's fine, but I know it's better for the web service calls to be batched up if possible, except there's a tradeoff between large granularity web service DTOs, versus short-running transactions on the database.  This particular scenario does not require a "business transaction", where all or none items are processed, I'm just looking to achieve the best balance of message size vs. number of web service calls vs. database transactions.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chatty interfaces (i.e. lots and lots of messages) will tend to have a high overhead from dispatching the incoming message (and, on the client, the reply) to the correct code to process the message (this will be a fixed cost per message). While big messages tend to use the resources in processing the message.

Additionally a lot of web service calls in progress will mean a lot of TCP/IP connections to manage, and concurrency issues (including locking in a database) might become an issue.

But without some details of the processing of the message it is hard to be specific, other than the general advice against chatty interfaces because of the fixed overheads.

Answer (score 2):

Measure first, optimize later. Unless you can make a back-of-the-envelope estimate that shows that the simplest solution yields unacceptably high loads, try it, establish good supervisory measurements, see how it performs and scales. **Then** start thinking about how much to batch and where.

This approach, of course, requires you to be able to change the web service interface after deployment, so you need a **versioning** approach to deal with clients which may not have been redesigned, supporting several WS versions in parallel. But not thinking about versioning almost always traps you in suboptimal interfaces, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**Abstract the message queue**

and have a swappable message queue backend. This way you can **test** many backends and give yourself an easy bail-out should you pick the wrong one or grow to like a new one that appears. The overhead of messaging is usually packing and handling the request. Different systems are designed for different levels traffic and different symmetries over time.

If you abstract out the basic features you can swap the mechanics in and out as your needs change, or are more accurately assessed.

You can also translate messages from differing queue types at various portions of the application or message route as the recipient's stresses change because they are handling, for example 1000:1/s vs 10:1/s on a higher level.

**Good Luck**